# How to get distinct values from a none relation FileMaker Pro database

Tags: filemaker

I have a FileMaker Pro database the was create by another person when the created it years ago it was not relational. It has many contacts and each contact is assigned to a single group. I want to get a distict list of those groups from that database. So if I started with say

group 1
group 1
group 2
group 3
group 7
group 3

I would end up with just groups 1,2,3,and 7 once each

than I can import them into the new database to make it relational so one contact can belong to more than one group

but I can't seem to figure out how to get that list. If someone could help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by group, then export into, say, tab-separated file, and in the export dialog check the "group by" flag for the group field. The resulting file will have only distinct groups.

Comment: so export it from original import into new they should have a group by flag in the import

Comment: Right, after it's exported, import it back into a new table of groups.  Then add a table for group membership, and write a one-time script to loop over existing records and create new membership records for their old group.